# What's the best practice to reverse engineering a binary file in windows?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

In my case it's written in `c/c++`,if that matters.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you will be hard pressed to get anything back besides assembly code.

Comment: @Anders, kinda like saying you'd be hard pressed to get anything back but a-z from a book on Shakespeare.

Comment: @GalacticJello imagine getting a book of Shakespeare where every other line says to be continued on another page and having the pages in a pile on the floor and the only thing you know about the book is that its about a king of some sort.

Comment: @anders: google 'hex-rays decompiler comparison'

Comment: @Igor, I didn't say it couldn't be done but its normally a tremendous effort for any larger more complex programs if you want make sense of the code without any context info or comments.

Comment: As for assembly, just look for a lot of "call <func>, cmp eax, 0" followed by "jne" statements...  That's basically "int resultCode = CheckPassword();  if (resultCode != SUCCESS) LogError();" type-of-pattern.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There is an entire SE site for that now :-)

Answer (score 8):

IDA rocks.
[IDA Disassembler](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/)

Answer (score 3):

Most reverser's are still gurus. You should first ask yourself *why* am I reversing?

There are a few main reasons I can think of.

1. You are trying to crack a copy protection mechanism, pirate software, or cheat in a video game.
2. You work for an Antivirus Company and need to understand the virus or the latest threat. Or are a government trying to prevent war or espionage.
3. You are beginning in programming, and are erroneously taking the approach of learning by tinkering.
4. You are a competitor and cannot figure out something (usually small) that they did.

In all of these cases, the true objective is small (a single algorithm for example), even though the ammount of code is large.

**#1 Hacking / Cracking / and Cheating**

> This is pretty easy actually. You just need to defeat the *multiple* anti circumvention measures. Without getting caught. The penalties for getting caught are high. DMCA violations, getting CD KEY banned from game, lawsuits... Any good debugger will do. Wikipedia has a good article on Windows debuggers. Some are free, some are not. Be sure to enable all anti circumvention measures and hack with your network disabled.

**#2 Professional Researcher**

> They have asked what you asked, a long time ago.

**#3 Beginner Programmer**

> Computer programming is not for the this looks easy I'll figure it out types... Even the most experienced programmers fail without documentation, samples, and examples. At the least, understand the Windows API, the docs are on MSDN.microsoft.com. **This will teach you what you need to know**.

**#4 Competitor**

> This is the most debated form of reverse engineering. You will need extensive knowledge of APIs used in the system. In this case, you need to know some of Windows APIs by heart. If you don't reversing a competitors code will be very difficult. What you do, is figure out *educated guess* which known API the program must use to do a speciffic task.
>
> For example, if it prints a message box to the screen, set a breakpoint on the Windows API: MessageBoxW. Then look at the callstack to see where the code was executed from in the program, and step back through the code (with your brain..) and figure out what you need to know.

### Reverse engineering takes hours

Antivirus authors likely have automated the Windows API (which could take *years*) to look for stuff that is common in malicious code. Tools that are under $100 are usually not very automated, so you'll use your brain alot.

Comment: I'd like to add (as happening to myself) "recovering compatibility with legacy file format that the no-longer-available programmer left undocumented"...

Comment: There is a fifth option, that has become increasingly common, especially in games.  You want to modify an existing piece of software to do something it wasn't originally written for, and the original developer did not create an explicit way to do this.  (I.e. you want to create a [mod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_(video_gaming)).)  This is often done with either the implicit or explicit blessing of the original author.

Comment: This is a weak answer. It doesn't answer the direct question at all and in fact, it seems like to just tries to discourage someone from learning reverse engineering. It is not realistic or substantiated in any way. For example, I find RE *easier* than "regular" programming, and a lot more rewarding. Of course he can't just "learn by playing", but OP made no reference to doing this at all. Reverse engineering is a real profession and it's not just for freaks of nature, prodigies, or weirdos, and in fact the best way to learn is by playing and being curious.

Answer (score 2):

you missed a few more reasons,
curiosity to learn how things are done where they are not publicly documented,
sometimes its the Himalayas appeal for us nerds out there, why do it because its there,
and mistrust paranoia, are they doing the right thing, are they ethical to the mass populous?
All the ones you listed are probably the more common though sadly.

It is a lot of effort but if the reason is learning, Any tool is good, I am definitely no guru (some of the people I have seen out there are oh so fast), but I find if you take the approach, decompile, copy a sections at a time in essence re-writing the system while stubbing calls that have not yet been copied you can reverse the design and determine algorithms used.

Answer (score 0):

[OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) is another free tool for reverse-engineering on Windows alongside IDA. You can find plenty of tutorials and plugins, scripts etc. from [Tuts 4 You](http://tuts4you.com/download.php) for both tools ("Lena's reversing for newbies" series is a great introduction to using Olly).

Comment: OllyDbg is good.  But similar to "The Most Interesting Man in the World" prefers Dos Equis, I can state that I have used both, and while not as interestng, "I prefer IDA".

Comment: I guess you should update your question to be "what's the best way to reverse engineer a game I'm playing to get around the copy protection" instead of "What's the best practice to reverse engineering a binary file in windows".  lol

Comment: @wamp your question does not state the requirement that the given solution is free, only the best practice. If the most efficient use of time & money is to buy a tool to do the job, then the 'best practice' is non-free.

Comment: @wamp actually there's a freeware version, which is quite enough to deal with most of Win32 binaries