# Are Windows system files protected against reverse engineering?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

I'm doing an experiment related to my PhD research. I need to know for sure whether the .exe files located in Windows/system/ directory (such as cmd.exe, notepad.exe, etc) are all non-obfuscated or they have some kind of obfuscation or protection against reverse engineering.

Comment: You should be responsive if you are asking any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most microsoft system binaries remove RTTI and strip symbols. You can download debug symbols for lots of the public/supported libraries/functions, for actual binary analysis I would recommend IDA and the MSVC class information loader plugin.

Comment: Does that mean if I can download debug symbols for a windows binary file (such as calc.exe, notepad.exe, etc), then it's not obfuscated/protected against reverse engineering?

Comment: @MostafaE.Saleh: are you asking from a legal or technical point of view?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Technical point of view. Because in my experiment, the files should be non-obfuscated or else I would have wrong result. That's why I need to make sure that these files are not obfuscated

Comment: All files are 'binary files' - however, to answer your question they supply debug symbols for their supported libaries, as noted in my above comment. To be honest I am doubtful of your claim of research for graduate level work, considering that the exposition of the process is so inherent of grad work.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering a binary file has been discussed on the link below:
[What's the best practice to reverse engineering a binary file in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633488/whats-the-best-practice-to-reverse-engineering-a-binary-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can't say 100% surely that any windows system file is protected against reverse engineering until anyone tried to do it.
Anyhow Windows (or any OS) will provide max protection for their system files. This link can help you to guide what type of protection provided by Windows for system files. 
[Description of the Windows File Protection feature](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193)

There are many tools/dissemblers/protocols available that can helps to inject piece of code or crack or do act of reverse engineering. I would conclude yes, windows provide protection but anyone can drill if not today, maybe in future.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the link you provided talks about Windows File Protection (WFP) which prevents programs from replacing critical Windows system files. My question is more about if code obfuscation techniques are used in windows executable files ?

Comment: yes, I knew my answer won't give you exact answer but I tried to give some clue. Anyhow your questing seems like a discussion topic than a typical question.

Comment: I wasn't discussing. I just needed Yes/No answer. Does windows obfuscates its files or not ?

Comment: I don't know then... I need to dig this topic. I will try to give exatact answer next time.